Stuck in a loop of pyhton3 reinstall and sudo apt-get update have dependency of python
I am trying to re-install python3 since getting errors in executing any python command
root@NCI-NGC-D-GPN-1:~# sudo python3 -version
sudo: python3: command not found


However, while re-installing I got below error
root@NCI-NGC-D-GPN-1:~# sudo apt-get install --reinstall python3
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree
Reading state information... Done
0 upgraded, 0 newly installed, 1 reinstalled, 0 to remove and 9 not upgraded.
1 not fully installed or removed.
Need to get 0 B/8,710 B of archives.
After this operation, 0 B of additional disk space will be used.
dpkg: warning: files list file for package 'python2.7' missing; assuming package has no files currently installed
(Reading database ... 165221 files and directories currently installed.)
Preparing to unpack .../python3_3.5.1-3_amd64.deb ...
/var/lib/dpkg/info/python3.prerm: 5: py3clean: Permission denied
dpkg: warning: old python3 package pre-removal script subprocess returned error exit status 126
dpkg: trying script from the new package instead ...
/var/lib/dpkg/tmp.ci/prerm: 5: py3clean: Permission denied
dpkg: error processing archive /var/cache/apt/archives/python3_3.5.1-3_amd64.deb (--unpack):
 new python3 package pre-removal script subprocess returned error exit status 126
/var/lib/dpkg/info/python3.postinst: 47: py3compile: Permission denied
dpkg: error while cleaning up:
 installed python3 package post-installation script subprocess returned error exit status 126
Errors were encountered while processing:
 /var/cache/apt/archives/python3_3.5.1-3_amd64.deb
E: Sub-process /usr/bin/dpkg returned an error code (1)
root@NCI-NGC-D-GPN-1:~#


I corrected the permission via command "sudo chmod +x /usr/bin/py3clean"
Then force-remove python3 so got this error"
root@NCI-NGC-D-GPN-1:~# sudo dpkg -r --force-remove-reinstreq python3
dpkg: dependency problems prevent removal of python3:
 dh-python depends on python3:any.
 dh-python depends on python3-distutils | python3 (<< 3.6.5~rc1-1); however:
  Package python3-distutils is not installed.
  Package python3 is to be removed.
 dh-python depends on python3:any.
 dh-python depends on python3-distutils | python3 (<< 3.6.5~rc1-1); however:
  Package python3-distutils is not installed.
  Package python3 is to be removed.

dpkg: error processing package python3 (--remove):
 dependency problems - not removing
Errors were encountered while processing:
 python3
root@NCI-NGC-D-GPN-1:~#


root@NCI-NGC-D-GPN-1:~# sudo apt-get install libpython3.7-stdlib
Reading package lists... 0%
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree
Reading state information... Done
The following additional packages will be installed:
  libffi6 libpython3.7-minimal
The following NEW packages will be installed:
  libffi6 libpython3.7-minimal libpython3.7-stdlib
0 upgraded, 3 newly installed, 0 to remove and 9 not upgraded.
1 not fully installed or removed.
Need to get 2,247 kB/2,256 kB of archives.
After this operation, 12.2 MB of additional disk space will be used.
Get:1 http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu xenial/main amd64 libffi6 amd64 3.2.1-4 [17.8 kB]
Get:2 http://us.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu bionic/universe amd64 libpython3.7-minimal amd64 3.7.0~b3-1 [544 kB]
Get:3 http://us.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu bionic/universe amd64 libpython3.7-stdlib amd64 3.7.0~b3-1 [1,685 kB]
Fetched 2,247 kB in 4s (615 kB/s)
Selecting previously unselected package libffi6:amd64.
dpkg: warning: files list file for package 'python2.7' missing; assuming package has no files currently installed
(Reading database ... 165221 files and directories currently installed.)
Preparing to unpack .../libffi6_3.2.1-4_amd64.deb ...
Unpacking libffi6:amd64 (3.2.1-4) ...
Selecting previously unselected package libpython3.7-minimal:amd64.
Preparing to unpack .../libpython3.7-minimal_3.7.0~b3-1_amd64.deb ...
Unpacking libpython3.7-minimal:amd64 (3.7.0~b3-1) ...
Selecting previously unselected package libpython3.7-stdlib:amd64.
Preparing to unpack .../libpython3.7-stdlib_3.7.0~b3-1_amd64.deb ...
Unpacking libpython3.7-stdlib:amd64 (3.7.0~b3-1) ...
dpkg: error processing package python3 (--configure):
 package is in a very bad inconsistent state; you should
 reinstall it before attempting configuration
Setting up libffi6:amd64 (3.2.1-4) ...
Setting up libpython3.7-minimal:amd64 (3.7.0~b3-1) ...
Setting up libpython3.7-stdlib:amd64 (3.7.0~b3-1) ...
Processing triggers for libc-bin (2.31-0ubuntu9.3) ...
Errors were encountered while processing:
 python3
E: Sub-process /usr/bin/dpkg returned an error code (1)
root@NCI-NGC-D-GPN-1:~#



Tried manual configure
root@NCI-NGC-D-GPN-1:~# sudo rm /var/lib/dpkg/lock*
root@NCI-NGC-D-GPN-1:~# sudo dpkg --configure -a

then tried to remove dependency forcefully
root@NCI-NGC-D-GPN-1:~# sudo dpkg --remove --force-remove-reinstreq --force-depends python3
dpkg: warning: overriding problem because --force enabled:
dpkg: warning: package is in a very bad inconsistent state; you should
 reinstall it before attempting a removal
dpkg: warning: files list file for package 'python2.7' missing; assuming package has no files currently installed
(Reading database ... 165808 files and directories currently installed.)
Removing python3 (3.5.1-3) ...
/var/lib/dpkg/info/python3.prerm: 5: py3clean: Permission denied
dpkg: error processing package python3 (--remove):
 installed python3 package pre-removal script subprocess returned error exit status 126
/var/lib/dpkg/info/python3.postinst: 47: py3compile: Permission denied
dpkg: error while cleaning up:
 installed python3 package post-installation script subprocess returned error exit status 126
Errors were encountered while processing:
 python3


Now I am stuck on this and not able to install anything further. Please help how to break this deadlock.
I am trying to repair python as none of the python commands are working and I am unable to reinstall/uninstall it as well.
